# Python not getting the right value in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, python-2.7, excel-formula, win32com

I want to color the interior of a cell according to it's content, however when I'm accessing its value I'm always getting '1.0', the value is calculated.

Colorisation code :

```
def _colorizeTop10RejetsSheet(self):
    """Colore les position de la page "Top 10 Rejets" """
    start_position = (5, 12)
    last_line = 47
    for x in range(start_position[0], last_line+1):
        current_cell = self.workbook.Sheets("Top 10 Rejets").Cells(x, start_position[1])
        current_cell.Interior.Color = self._computePositionColor(current_cell.Value)

def _computePositionColor(self, position):
    """Colore les position de 1 a 5 en rouge de et 6 a 10 en orange"""
    if position < 6:
        return self.RED
    elif position < 11:
        return self.ORANGE
    else:
        return self.WHITE
```

Excel cell code :

```
=SI(ESTNA(RECHERCHEV(CONCATENER(TEXTE($F23;0);TEXTE($G23;"00");$H23;$I23);Données!$J:$P;7;FAUX));MAX(Données!$P:$P);RECHERCHEV(CONCATENER(TEXTE($F23;0);TEXTE($G23;"00");$H23;$I23);Données!$J:$P;7;FAUX))
```

How could I get the calculated value?

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm communicating with Excel through win32com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the beginning of the _colorizeTop10Rejets method did the trick

```
self.xl.Calculate()
```

self.xl is the object returned by win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')